# Send array as POST request parameter to PHP - Swift

Tags: php, swift

I'm sending the "formKATID" parameter to PHP. I want to send more than one "formKATID". For example, I want to select the data in the database where KATEGORI.ID = 6,7,8. That's why I have defined more than one formKATID in bodyObject. But it doesn't work that way. How can I submit more than one "formKATID"? I print the "ExistCount" row with json_encode and try to extract the count output by swift, but it comes with a null value. There is a problem with the Array I sent.

**PHP**
    ...

```
     $connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,
                                "PWD"=>$pwd,
                                "Database"=>$databaseName);

    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

    $formKATID = $_POST['formKATID'];

    $tsql = "SELECT ... IN(".implode(', ',$formKATID).")";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);

    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {

        $paketCount = $row['ExistCount'];

         $results[] = Array("Count" => $paketCount);
    }
     echo json_encode($results, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
    ?>
```

...

**SWIFT**

```
@objc func kategoriSaydır(){
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let bodyObject = ["formKATID": ["6", "7", "8"]] as [String : Any]
    request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: bodyObject, options: [])

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data else {
            // error
            return
        }
        do {
            if let baslik = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]] {
                for review in baslik {
                    if let soru_baslik = review["Count"] as? String {
                        let s = String(describing: soru_baslik)
                        print("kategoriItemCount", s)
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch let parseError { ... }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: What is the issue? Do you get an error in response? Your swift code looks right. Do you call `task.resume()`?

Comment: I print the "ExistCount" row with json_encode and try to extract the count output by swift, but it comes with a null value. There is a problem with the Array I sent.

Comment: I don't see errors in the code. Do you have an example of a valid request? You can create a request using Postman - https://www.postman.com.

Comment: When I try it in Postman, it returns null value, I think there is a problem with my php code. But I can't find the problem. @VladislavMarkov

Comment: I updated php code, Can you check it? Thank you. @VladislavMarkov

Comment: Okay. I'm sorry, I don't know much about PHP. You should add tag `PHP`. May be PHP developer will help you.

Comment: I am currently printing out of the post. I think there is a problem with the swift side. @VladislavMarkov

Comment: Could you give me code for cURL from Postman? You should press the button `Code` and copy code.

Comment: Why did you leave a solution? Thanks.@VladislavMarkov

Comment: I see you use url encoded parameters. It is the first error. But I got " null" with fixed parameters too. So I try to find the solution

Comment: Thank you I am waiting for your help. @VladislavMarkov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameters are url encoded.

You should add it:

```
public extension String {

    public func addingPercentEncodingForUrlQueryValue() -> String? {
        let generalDelimitersToEncode = ":#[]@"
        let subDelimitersToEncode = "!$&'()*+,;="

        var allowed = CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed
        allowed.remove(charactersIn: generalDelimitersToEncode + subDelimitersToEncode)

        return addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowed)
    }

}
```

And you can try this:

```
func generateParametersString(_ parameters: [String: Any]) -> String {
    let parameterArray = parameters.map { key, value -> String in
        guard let escapedKey = key.addingPercentEncodingForUrlQueryValue() else { return "" }

        if let stringValue = value as? String {
            guard let escapedValue = stringValue.addingPercentEncodingForUrlQueryValue() else { return "" }

            return "\(escapedKey)=\(escapedValue)"
        }

        if let arrayValue = value as? [Any] {
            var arrayParameter: [String] = []

            for index in 0..<arrayValue.count {
                var element: String
                if let stringElement = arrayValue[index] as? String {
                    element = stringElement
                } else {
                    element = "\(arrayValue[index])"
                }

                guard let escapedElement = element.addingPercentEncodingForUrlQueryValue() else { continue }

                arrayParameter.append("\(escapedKey)[]=\(escapedElement)")
            }

            return arrayParameter.joined(separator: "&")
        }

        guard let escapedValue = "\(value)".addingPercentEncodingForUrlQueryValue() else { return "" }

        return "\(escapedKey)=\(escapedValue)"
    }

    return parameterArray.joined(separator: "&")
}

@objc func kategoriSaydır(){
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let bodyObject = ["formKATID": ["6", "7", "8"]] as [String : Any]
    request.httpBody = generateParametersString(bodyObject).data(using: .utf8)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data else {
            // error
            return
        }
        do {
            if let baslik = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]] {
                for review in baslik {
                    if let soru_baslik = review["Count"] {
                        let s = String(describing: soru_baslik)
                        print("kategoriItemCount", s)
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch let parseError { ... }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: @deneov I have updated my answer several times. Now it works.

Comment: @deneov Did you use my edited answer? I get the correct response and json object.

Comment: @deneov Your server uses http. Do you have a dictionary `App Transport Security Settings` with an element `Allow Arbitrary Load` with value `YES` in Info.plist?

Comment: Blank data came, thank you worked, you saved me from health :)